# How can a Pandas Data frame with datetime index be grouped by date in a way that values belonging to the date are split into multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a dataframe:

```
  timestamp                                       value
0 2019-07-12 18:00:00                             8.46
1 2019-07-13 06:00:00                            12.02
2 2019-07-13 18:00:00                            15.58
3 2019-07-14 06:00:00                            16.29
4 2019-07-14 18:00:00                            17.00
```

I want to transform in to:

```
 timestamp                               X1       X2
0 2019-07-12                             8.46     NaN
1 2019-07-13                             12.02    15.58
2 2019-07-14                             16.29    17.00
```

How can this be done?

I tried `pd.groupby` with `Grouper` and then doing a for loop like below:

```py
for ix, i in resampled_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq="1D")):
    print(i.head())
```

No luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
# Convert to datetime (if not already)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
# Get Series of Dates from Timestamp
dates = df['timestamp'].dt.date
df = (
    # Pivot on dates in index, and columns based on rows per group
    df.pivot_table(index=dates,
                   columns=df['value'].groupby(dates).cumcount() + 1,
                   values='value')
        .add_prefix('X')  # Add X in Front of Columns
        .reset_index()  # Make dates a column
)
```

`df`:

```
    timestamp     X1     X2
0  2019-07-12   8.46    NaN
1  2019-07-13  12.02  15.58
2  2019-07-14  16.29  17.00
```